# select taking 9.+ seconds. how to re-write it better?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this select:

```
select t.id, c.user, t.title, pp.foto, t.data from topics t
inner join cadastro c on t.user = c.id
left join profile_picture pp on t.user = pp.user
left join (
    select c.topic, MAX(c.data) cdata from comments c
    group by c.topic
)c on t.id = c.topic
where t.community = ?
order by ifnull(cdata, t.data) desc
limit 15
```

I want to select topics and order them by their date or the date of the topic comments, if it has comments.

Unfortunately, this is taking more than 9 seconds.

[image]
I don't think the problem here is indexing, but the way I am writing the select itself.

```
`topics` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(1000),
  `community` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`user`) REFERENCES cadastro (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`community`) REFERENCES discussion (`id`)
)

`comments` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `topic` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20),
  `delete` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`user`) REFERENCES cadastro (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`topic`) REFERENCES topics (`id`)
)
```

Comment: You are abusing the alias `c`. Try to give some different names.

Comment: Not always, but sometimes it can help to select the blob data out last (as in make the query a subquery without a join to `pp`, but keeping the limit, and then join the subquery results to pp).

Comment: Single letter variables make it a pain to read this. Your tablenames are short enough, just drop the aliases.

Comment: I would denormalise your data structure and would store the latest comment date in the topics table and use triggers to keep it updated.

Answer (score 3):

Your `EXPLAIN` gives you a strong hint. The first row in that results says, `using temporary, using filesort` implying that it's not using a an index.

It might be possible to improve this query by adding indexes and removing some conditionals, but I think in this case a better solution exists.

Why not add a new column to `topics` that indicates the last time a comment was added? (like a `last_modified`). Every time a comment gets added, just update that column for that topic as well.

It's effectively denormalizing this. I think this a valid usecase and it's always going to be faster than fixing this messy query.

Comment: thank you for the idea! it will help a lot, for sure.

Comment: is it possible to create a trigger? or should I update programatelly? @Evert

Comment: Yes, you can do this via a trigger. Given the option of doing it programmatically or via a trigger I tend to do this in code, but both are valid approaches.

Answer (score 3):

You are performing a full table scan on the table `comments` on every query. How many rows does it have? At least create the following index:

```
comments (topic, data);
```

to avoid reading the whole table every time.

Comment: comments has 300.418 rows. I'll add this index!

Answer (score 2):

I know you've said you don't think the problem is indexing, but 9 out of 10 times I've had this problem that's exactly what it's been down to.

Ensure you have an index created on each table that you're using in the query and include the columns specified in the join.

Also, as NiVeR said, don't use the same alias multiple times.

Here's a refactoring of that query, unsure if I've mixed up or missed a column name/alias or two though.

```
select t.id, c.user, t.title, pp.foto, t.data from topics t
inner join cadastro c on t.user = c.id
left join profile_picture pp on t.user = pp.user
left join (
    select com.topic, MAX(com.data) comdata from comments com
    group by com.topic
)com1 on t.id = com1.topic
where t.community = ?
order by ifnull(com1.comdata, t.data) desc
limit 15
```

Comment: You're 100% correct that his problem is poor indexes.

Comment: Avoid full table scans in nested queries like the plague. They're a performance killer.